# GNU Emacs Calculator with SBCL

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl

I've been reading the [GNU Emacs Calculator manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/index.html#Top) in search of directions for how to programmatically call the existing functions in a lisp program.

I've examined the section called 'Programming', but it seems to be more related to extending the calculator, rather than programming using the calculator. There is a section called 'Calling Calc from your Lisp Programs' which talks about a `calc-eval` function available to programmers, but so far, I have not been able to call that function in SBCL.

It seems that it is possible to call the calculator functions programmatically from [Emacs Lisp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Calc), but I'd be curious to know if there is similar functionality in SBCL too.

Answer (score 8):

[GNU Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) [Calculator](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/) is an [Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/) program.

[SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) is a [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) implementation.

ELisp and CL are *different* languages (from the same Lisp family).

This means that you cannot run the Emacs Calculator from SBCL directly.

However, I wrote an [ELisp compatibility layer](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/cllib/elisp.lisp) which allowed me to run [Emacs Calendar](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Calendar_002fDiary.html) from [CLISP](http://clisp.org) (also a Common Lisp implementation).
It should allow you to load Emacs Calculator in SBCL and run its code.

Comment: Alright, I will check it out! I've gotta head out for an event, but as soon as I get back, I'll check this out and let you know how it went. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to run this code. It doesn't load properly in sbcl. It says that clocc:src;cllib;base does not exist, and that cllib does not designate any package, and that the package el does not exist.

Comment: I realized my mistake from above, and downloaded the whole project and tried to install it. Unfortunately, I get a compile error when trying to compile port-ext in cllib. I will report the bug

Comment: I've installed the CLLIB from the CLOCC project. I still am struggling, however, to get access to the calculator application. Any idea on how to do this? Even when I do (el::require 'calc-ext), the system doesn't know where to find the calculator package. I looked in my /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/ directory but the system won't load any of the .elc's there.

Comment: You cannot load `.elc` - they are ELisp compiled files. You should figure out how SBCL `load` work - where it finds the lisp files to load. At the very least you should be able to load the files with a full path.

Comment: I tried to el::load calculator.elc at /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/, but i got an error that the \*closio-method\* is nil. I also tried sbcl's load, then got I'm missing a definition for dispatch function #\[. When I tried to el::load calc-ext (and for many other files) I got another dispatch function error. When I did the sbcl's load I get the same errors. Is this happening because there's some file I should be loading first that I don't know about? The only file I can load right now is calc-loaddefs.el at /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/calc/, but I still get all the same errors.

Comment: Forget `cl:load`. Not gonna work. You need to chase all the missing stuff and `el:load` the appropriate files.